How to prepare string to paste in multiple Google Sheets cells skipping some cells?
I am trying to prepare a string in Javascript & putting it in clipboard, so that I can paste it in a Google Sheet one row multiple cells. I can insert the tab \t where I want the part of string to go to next column cell. E.g. X\tY\tZ will get pasted in cell A1 as X, A2 as Y & A3 as Z.
My question is, how do I prepare the string that it skips a column.
I have cells A1, A2, A3 & A4. The values I want in A1 is X, in A2 is Y, & I want to leave A3 as it is when I paste, & Z in A4. Similar to X\tY\t*Z but is there anything I can insert in place of *?

Can you share any details about this, so that the community can replicate your current situation?

When you paste over cells, the new data replaces the old. You can add a blank column as \t\t but that will make the column blank instead of keeping the value already there. The easiest solution would be to re-order columns so that the column you want to keep is not in the middle of columns you want to replace.

Are there values in the cells you want to skip or are they blank? As @doubleunary said, not possible to skip via paste, so hopefully the answer is blank....

@pgSystemTester unfortunately I don't control the sheet, it is a shared one, with formulas in between columns.

@doubleunary I think that's the answer, if you add it as answer, I will accept it.

When you paste over cells, the new data replaces the old. You can add a blank column as \t\t but that will make the column blank instead of keeping the value already there. The easiest solution would be to re-order columns so that the column you want to keep is not in the middle of columns you want to replace.
